# PyQt4 slot system transition to PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I followed some tutorial online to learn about threading with PyQt but the example uses PyQt4 and I'm using PyQt5. I read this link to get some information: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html.

But I still don't understand how I should change my example below for it to work with PyQt5.

What this example is supposed to do is show the cpu percentage on a progress bar, and the reason why I'm using a thread is so the progress bar value will change when the cpu load changes.

So FYI the code below is code that works with PyQt4 but not with version 5, it would be helpful if somebody could show me the right way to do it with PyQt5.

My example code:

```
import sys
import os
import sysInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication

from test import Ui_Form

class MainUiClass(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainUiClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.connect(self.threadclass, SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), self.updateProgressBar)

    def updateProgressBar(self, val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)

class ThreadClass(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            val = sysInfo.getCPU()  # get cpu load
            self.emit(SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainUiClass()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Are you having any actual problems with the code shown? If so, be very detailed and specific in describing those problems *in the question itself*. Do not put relevant information into comments please: use the edit button under the question instead.

Comment: It is a bad idea to put the code that compiles your UI parent class into your script, but I understand if this is a work in progress.

Comment: that's the old way of emitting signals. Not sure it works in PyQt5. I found http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html useful.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I removed it from the code, but it was there because this is indeed a work in progress.

Comment: @Aidenhjj would you mind changing my example to the new way of emitting signals? That would help me a lot!

Comment: You say it doesn't work. How?

Comment: It didn't work because the code in my example was from a PyQt4 example, which uses an older method to declare signals. The answer from eyllanesc should get me started now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to declare a signal is changed from pyqt4 to pyqt5:

```
class MainUiClass(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainUiClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.cpuValueChanged.connect(self.updateProgressBar)
        self.threadclass.start()


    def updateProgressBar(self, val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)

class ThreadClass(QThread):
    cpuValueChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            val = sysInfo.getCPU()  # get cpu load
            self.cpuValueChanged.emit(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainUiClass()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the answer I was looking for. I'll try fiddle around with the code to understand signals and slots better in Qt.